# Increasing the time by one hour - Android.Time

Tags: android, datetime

I use the [Time class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) to get the current time, and I need to get it in the `mm.hh` format. To do this, I use the following approach:

```
Time time = new Time();
time.setToNow();
String currentTime = time.hour + ":" + time.minute;
```

Can I increase the current time, for example, by one hour in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Time time = new Time();
time.setToNow();

++time.hour; // increase 1 hour
time.normalize(false);
```

Comment: It works! I think the `time.normalize` should be set to `true`. It will be useful if it's necessary to increase the time for a few hours before midnight.

Answer (score 2):

First increase your hour and then format it again:

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
String currentTime = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

if you need hour in 24-format use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Time time = new Time();
time.setToNow();
time.hour++;
time.toMillis(false);
```